# PHPMYADMIN Exception: Specified context ("\SqlParser\Contexts\ContextMySql50724") does not exist

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, xdebug

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04,Zend framework 3, and integrated Xdebugger with Visual studio. Now when I start debugger in visual studio  and reload phpmyadmin web page on my localhost `localhost/phpmyadmin` in browser, it shows me this error

[image]

Even though I did not put any breakpoint but everytime it still stops at the location shown in screenshot above.

**Xdebug.ini**

```
xdebug.show_error_trace = 0
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with MariaDb100408 version and I solved it editing the file /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Context.php adding this at the begining

```
    if ($context == "MariaDb100408") {
        $context = "MariaDb100300";
    }
```

This is not a good solution, but it works for me

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyadmin - SQL parser unable to locate SQLfile context.

Take a look at below links, this may help you to solve this issue.

---Here you can see cause of an issue---

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13728#issuecomment-338804494

---Here you will find the code change to Improve SQL context loading ---

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/commit/9b56a083c53fd17d06d542ec21aac9a31093d3dc

Thanks,
Nil's

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. It solved by restarting mysql and apache services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but came to realize that when **closing Xdebug in visual studio solves the problem**. It seems like visual studio is debugging under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

Just copy this code below and save as `ContextMariaDb100408.php` in the directory `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Contexts/`.

```
<?php

/**
 * Context for MariaDB 10.4.8
 *
 * This file was auto-generated.
 *
 * @see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/reserved-words/
 */

namespace PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Contexts;

use PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Context;
use PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Token;

/**
 * Context for MariaDB 10.4.8
 *
 * @category   Contexts
 *
 * @license    https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt GPL-2.0+
 */
class ContextMariaDb100408 extends Context
{
    /**
     * List of keywords.
     *
     * The value associated to each keyword represents its flags.
     *
     * @see Token::FLAG_KEYWORD_RESERVED Token::FLAG_KEYWORD_COMPOSED
     *      Token::FLAG_KEYWORD_DATA_TYPE Token::FLAG_KEYWORD_KEY
     *      Token::FLAG_KEYWORD_FUNCTION
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $KEYWORDS = array(
        'AT' => 1, 'DO' => 1, 'IO' => 1, 'NO' => 1, 'XA' => 1,
        'ANY' => 1, 'CPU' => 1, 'END' => 1, 'IPC' => 1, 'NDB' => 1, 'NEW' => 1,
        'ONE' => 1, 'ROW' => 1, 'XID' => 1,
        'BOOL' => 1, 'BYTE' => 1, 'CODE' => 1, 'CUBE' => 1, 'DATA' => 1, 'DISK' => 1,
        'ENDS' => 1, 'FAST' => 1, 'FILE' => 1, 'FULL' => 1, 'HASH' => 1, 'HELP' => 1,
        'HOST' => 1, 'LAST' => 1, 'LESS' => 1, 'LIST' => 1, 'LOGS' => 1, 'MODE' => 1,
        'NAME' => 1, 'NEXT' => 1, 'NONE' => 1, 'ONLY' => 1, 'OPEN' => 1, 'PAGE' => 1,
        'PORT' => 1, 'PREV' => 1, 'SLOW' => 1, 'SOME' => 1, 'STOP' => 1, 'THAN' => 1,
        'TYPE' => 1, 'VIEW' => 1, 'WAIT' => 1, 'WORK' => 1, 'X509' => 1,
        'AFTER' => 1, 'BEGIN' => 1, 'BLOCK' => 1, 'BTREE' => 1, 'CACHE' => 1,
        'CHAIN' => 1, 'CLOSE' => 1, 'ERROR' => 1, 'EVENT' => 1, 'EVERY' => 1,
        'FIRST' => 1, 'FIXED' => 1, 'FLUSH' => 1, 'FOUND' => 1, 'HOSTS' => 1,
        'LEVEL' => 1, 'LOCAL' => 1, 'LOCKS' => 1, 'MERGE' => 1, 'MUTEX' => 1,
        'NAMES' => 1, 'NCHAR' => 1, 'NEVER' => 1, 'OWNER' => 1, 'PHASE' => 1,
        'PROXY' => 1, 'QUERY' => 1, 'QUICK' => 1, 'RELAY' => 1, 'RESET' => 1,
        'RTREE' => 1, 'SHARE' => 1, 'SLAVE' => 1, 'START' => 1, 'SUPER' => 1,
        'SWAPS' => 1, 'TYPES' => 1, 'UNTIL' => 1, 'VALUE' => 1,
        'ACTION' => 1, 'ALWAYS' => 1, 'BACKUP' => 1, 'BINLOG' => 1, 'CIPHER' => 1,
        'CLIENT' => 1, 'COMMIT' => 1, 'ENABLE' => 1, 'ENGINE' => 1, 'ERRORS' => 1,
        'ESCAPE' => 1, 'EVENTS' => 1, 'EXPIRE' => 1, 'EXPORT' => 1, 'FAULTS' => 1,
        'FIELDS' => 1, 'FILTER' => 1, 'GLOBAL' => 1, 'GRANTS' => 1, 'IMPORT' => 1,
        'ISSUER' => 1, 'LEAVES' => 1, 'MASTER' => 1, 'MEDIUM' => 1, 'MEMORY' => 1,
        'MODIFY' => 1, 'NUMBER' => 1, 'OFFSET' => 1, 'PARSER' => 1, 'PLUGIN' => 1,
        'RELOAD' => 1, 'REMOVE' => 1, 'REPAIR' => 1, 'RESUME' => 1, 'ROLLUP' => 1,
        'SERVER' => 1, 'SIGNED' => 1, 'SIMPLE' => 1, 'SOCKET' => 1, 'SONAME' => 1,
        'SOUNDS' => 1, 'SOURCE' => 1, 'STARTS' => 1, 'STATUS' => 1, 'STRING' => 1,
        'TABLES' => 1,
        'ACCOUNT' => 1, 'ANALYSE' => 1, 'CHANGED' => 1, 'CHANNEL' => 1, 'COLUMNS' => 1,
        'COMMENT' => 1, 'COMPACT' => 1, 'CONTEXT' => 1, 'CURRENT' => 1, 'DEFINER' => 1,
        'DISABLE' => 1, 'DISCARD' => 1, 'DYNAMIC' => 1, 'ENGINES' => 1, 'EXECUTE' => 1,
        'FOLLOWS' => 1, 'GENERAL' => 1, 'HANDLER' => 1, 'INDEXES' => 1, 'INSTALL' => 1,
        'INVOKER' => 1, 'LOGFILE' => 1, 'MIGRATE' => 1, 'NO_WAIT' => 1, 'OPTIONS' => 1,
        'PARTIAL' => 1, 'PLUGINS' => 1, 'PREPARE' => 1, 'PROFILE' => 1, 'REBUILD' => 1,
        'RECOVER' => 1, 'RESTORE' => 1, 'RETURNS' => 1, 'ROUTINE' => 1, 'SESSION' => 1,
        'STACKED' => 1, 'STORAGE' => 1, 'SUBJECT' => 1, 'SUSPEND' => 1, 'UNICODE' => 1,
        'UNKNOWN' => 1, 'UPGRADE' => 1, 'USE_FRM' => 1, 'WITHOUT' => 1, 'WRAPPER' => 1,
        'CASCADED' => 1, 'CHECKSUM' => 1, 'DATAFILE' => 1, 'DUMPFILE' => 1,
        'EXCHANGE' => 1, 'EXTENDED' => 1, 'FUNCTION' => 1, 'LANGUAGE' => 1,
        'MAX_ROWS' => 1, 'MAX_SIZE' => 1, 'MIN_ROWS' => 1, 'NATIONAL' => 1,
        'NVARCHAR' => 1, 'PRECEDES' => 1, 'PRESERVE' => 1, 'PROFILES' => 1,
        'REDOFILE' => 1, 'RELAYLOG' => 1, 'ROLLBACK' => 1, 'SCHEDULE' => 1,
        'SECURITY' => 1, 'SEQUENCE' => 1, 'SHUTDOWN' => 1, 'SNAPSHOT' => 1,
        'SWITCHES' => 1, 'TRIGGERS' => 1, 'UNDOFILE' => 1, 'WARNINGS' => 1,
        'AGGREGATE' => 1, 'ALGORITHM' => 1, 'COMMITTED' => 1, 'DIRECTORY' => 1,
        'DUPLICATE' => 1, 'EXPANSION' => 1, 'IO_THREAD' => 1, 'ISOLATION' => 1,
        'NODEGROUP' => 1, 'PACK_KEYS' => 1, 'READ_ONLY' => 1, 'REDUNDANT' => 1,
        'SAVEPOINT' => 1, 'SQL_CACHE' => 1, 'TEMPORARY' => 1, 'TEMPTABLE' => 1,
        'UNDEFINED' => 1, 'UNINSTALL' => 1, 'VARIABLES' => 1,
        'COMPLETION' => 1, 'COMPRESSED' => 1, 'CONCURRENT' => 1, 'CONNECTION' => 1,
        'CONSISTENT' => 1, 'DEALLOCATE' => 1, 'IDENTIFIED' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL' => 1,
        'NDBCLUSTER' => 1, 'PARTITIONS' => 1, 'PERSISTENT' => 1, 'PLUGIN_DIR' => 1,
        'PRIVILEGES' => 1, 'REORGANIZE' => 1, 'REPEATABLE' => 1, 'ROW_FORMAT' => 1,
        'SQL_THREAD' => 1, 'TABLESPACE' => 1, 'TABLE_NAME' => 1, 'VALIDATION' => 1,
        'COLUMN_NAME' => 1, 'COMPRESSION' => 1, 'CURSOR_NAME' => 1, 'DIAGNOSTICS' => 1,
        'EXTENT_SIZE' => 1, 'MASTER_HOST' => 1, 'MASTER_PORT' => 1, 'MASTER_USER' => 1,
        'MYSQL_ERRNO' => 1, 'NONBLOCKING' => 1, 'PROCESSLIST' => 1, 'REPLICATION' => 1,
        'SCHEMA_NAME' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_DAY' => 1, 'TRANSACTION' => 1, 'UNCOMMITTED' => 1,
        'CATALOG_NAME' => 1, 'CLASS_ORIGIN' => 1, 'DEFAULT_AUTH' => 1,
        'DES_KEY_FILE' => 1, 'INITIAL_SIZE' => 1, 'MASTER_DELAY' => 1,
        'MESSAGE_TEXT' => 1, 'PARTITIONING' => 1, 'RELAY_THREAD' => 1,
        'SERIALIZABLE' => 1, 'SQL_NO_CACHE' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_HOUR' => 1,
        'SQL_TSI_WEEK' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_YEAR' => 1, 'SUBPARTITION' => 1,
        'COLUMN_FORMAT' => 1, 'INSERT_METHOD' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL_CA' => 1,
        'RELAY_LOG_POS' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_MONTH' => 1, 'SUBPARTITIONS' => 1,
        'AUTO_INCREMENT' => 1, 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH' => 1, 'KEY_BLOCK_SIZE' => 1,
        'MASTER_LOG_POS' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL_CRL' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL_KEY' => 1,
        'RELAY_LOG_FILE' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_MINUTE' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_SECOND' => 1,
        'TABLE_CHECKSUM' => 1, 'USER_RESOURCES' => 1,
        'AUTOEXTEND_SIZE' => 1, 'CONSTRAINT_NAME' => 1, 'DELAY_KEY_WRITE' => 1,
        'FILE_BLOCK_SIZE' => 1, 'MASTER_LOG_FILE' => 1, 'MASTER_PASSWORD' => 1,
        'MASTER_SSL_CERT' => 1, 'PARSE_GCOL_EXPR' => 1, 'REPLICATE_DO_DB' => 1,
        'SQL_AFTER_GTIDS' => 1, 'SQL_TSI_QUARTER' => 1, 'SUBCLASS_ORIGIN' => 1,
        'MASTER_SERVER_ID' => 1, 'REDO_BUFFER_SIZE' => 1, 'SQL_BEFORE_GTIDS' => 1,
        'STATS_PERSISTENT' => 1, 'UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE' => 1,
        'CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA' => 1, 'GROUP_REPLICATION' => 1, 'IGNORE_SERVER_IDS' => 1,
        'MASTER_SSL_CAPATH' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL_CIPHER' => 1, 'RETURNED_SQLSTATE' => 1,
        'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT' => 1, 'STATS_AUTO_RECALC' => 1,
        'CONSTRAINT_CATALOG' => 1, 'MASTER_RETRY_COUNT' => 1, 'MASTER_SSL_CRLPATH' => 1,
        'MAX_STATEMENT_TIME' => 1, 'REPLICATE_DO_TABLE' => 1, 'SQL_AFTER_MTS_GAPS' => 1,
        'STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES' => 1,
        'REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB' => 1,
        'MASTER_AUTO_POSITION' => 1, 'MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY' => 1,
        'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR' => 1, 'MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR' => 1,
        'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS' => 1, 'REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB' => 1,
        'REPLICATE_IGNORE_TABLE' => 1,
        'MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD' => 1, 'REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE' => 1,
        'MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR' => 1,
        'REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE' => 1,

        'AS' => 3, 'BY' => 3, 'IS' => 3, 'ON' => 3, 'OR' => 3, 'TO' => 3,
        'ADD' => 3, 'ALL' => 3, 'AND' => 3, 'ASC' => 3, 'DEC' => 3, 'DIV' => 3,
        'FOR' => 3, 'GET' => 3, 'NOT' => 3, 'OUT' => 3, 'SQL' => 3, 'SSL' => 3,
        'USE' => 3, 'XOR' => 3,
        'BOTH' => 3, 'CALL' => 3, 'CASE' => 3, 'DESC' => 3, 'DROP' => 3, 'DUAL' => 3,
        'EACH' => 3, 'ELSE' => 3, 'EXIT' => 3, 'FROM' => 3, 'INT1' => 3, 'INT2' => 3,
        'INT3' => 3, 'INT4' => 3, 'INT8' => 3, 'INTO' => 3, 'JOIN' => 3, 'KEYS' => 3,
        'KILL' => 3, 'LIKE' => 3, 'LOAD' => 3, 'LOCK' => 3, 'LONG' => 3, 'LOOP' => 3,
        'NULL' => 3, 'READ' => 3, 'ROWS' => 3, 'SHOW' => 3, 'THEN' => 3, 'TRUE' => 3,
        'UNDO' => 3, 'WHEN' => 3, 'WITH' => 3,
        'ALTER' => 3, 'CHECK' => 3, 'CROSS' => 3, 'FALSE' => 3, 'FETCH' => 3,
        'FORCE' => 3, 'GRANT' => 3, 'GROUP' => 3, 'INNER' => 3, 'INOUT' => 3,
        'LEAVE' => 3, 'LIMIT' => 3, 'LINES' => 3, 'ORDER' => 3, 'OUTER' => 3,
        'PURGE' => 3, 'RANGE' => 3, 'READS' => 3, 'RLIKE' => 3, 'TABLE' => 3,
        'UNION' => 3, 'USAGE' => 3, 'USING' => 3, 'WHERE' => 3, 'WHILE' => 3,
        'WRITE' => 3,
        'BEFORE' => 3, 'CHANGE' => 3, 'COLUMN' => 3, 'CREATE' => 3, 'CURSOR' => 3,
        'DELETE' => 3, 'ELSEIF' => 3, 'EXCEPT' => 3, 'EXISTS' => 3, 'FLOAT4' => 3,
        'FLOAT8' => 3, 'HAVING' => 3, 'IGNORE' => 3, 'INFILE' => 3, 'LINEAR' => 3,
        'OPTION' => 3, 'REGEXP' => 3, 'RENAME' => 3, 'RETURN' => 3, 'REVOKE' => 3,
        'SELECT' => 3, 'SIGNAL' => 3, 'STORED' => 3, 'UNLOCK' => 3, 'UPDATE' => 3,
        'ANALYZE' => 3, 'BETWEEN' => 3, 'CASCADE' => 3, 'COLLATE' => 3, 'DECLARE' => 3,
        'DELAYED' => 3, 'ESCAPED' => 3, 'EXPLAIN' => 3, 'FOREIGN' => 3, 'ITERATE' => 3,
        'LEADING' => 3, 'NATURAL' => 3, 'OUTFILE' => 3, 'PRIMARY' => 3, 'RELEASE' => 3,
        'REQUIRE' => 3, 'SCHEMAS' => 3, 'TRIGGER' => 3, 'VARYING' => 3, 'VIRTUAL' => 3,
        'CONTINUE' => 3, 'DAY_HOUR' => 3, 'DESCRIBE' => 3, 'DISTINCT' => 3,
        'ENCLOSED' => 3, 'MAXVALUE' => 3, 'MODIFIES' => 3, 'OPTIMIZE' => 3,
        'RESIGNAL' => 3, 'RESTRICT' => 3, 'SPECIFIC' => 3, 'SQLSTATE' => 3,
        'STARTING' => 3, 'TRAILING' => 3, 'UNSIGNED' => 3, 'ZEROFILL' => 3,
        'CONDITION' => 3, 'DATABASES' => 3, 'GENERATED' => 3, 'INTERSECT' => 3,
        'MIDDLEINT' => 3, 'PARTITION' => 3, 'PRECISION' => 3, 'PROCEDURE' => 3,
        'RECURSIVE' => 3, 'SENSITIVE' => 3, 'SEPARATOR' => 3,
        'ACCESSIBLE' => 3, 'ASENSITIVE' => 3, 'CONSTRAINT' => 3, 'DAY_MINUTE' => 3,
        'DAY_SECOND' => 3, 'OPTIONALLY' => 3, 'READ_WRITE' => 3, 'REFERENCES' => 3,
        'SQLWARNING' => 3, 'TERMINATED' => 3, 'YEAR_MONTH' => 3,
        'DISTINCTROW' => 3, 'HOUR_MINUTE' => 3, 'HOUR_SECOND' => 3, 'INSENSITIVE' => 3,
        'MASTER_BIND' => 3,
        'LOW_PRIORITY' => 3, 'SQLEXCEPTION' => 3, 'VARCHARACTER' => 3,
        'DETERMINISTIC' => 3, 'HIGH_PRIORITY' => 3, 'MINUTE_SECOND' => 3,
        'STRAIGHT_JOIN' => 3,
        'IO_AFTER_GTIDS' => 3, 'SQL_BIG_RESULT' => 3,
        'DAY_MICROSECOND' => 3, 'IO_BEFORE_GTIDS' => 3, 'OPTIMIZER_COSTS' => 3,
        'HOUR_MICROSECOND' => 3, 'SQL_SMALL_RESULT' => 3,
        'MINUTE_MICROSECOND' => 3, 'NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG' => 3, 'SECOND_MICROSECOND' => 3,
        'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS' => 3,
        'MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT' => 3,

        'GROUP BY' => 7, 'NOT NULL' => 7, 'ORDER BY' => 7, 'SET NULL' => 7,
        'AND CHAIN' => 7, 'FULL JOIN' => 7, 'IF EXISTS' => 7, 'LEFT JOIN' => 7,
        'LESS THAN' => 7, 'LOAD DATA' => 7, 'NO ACTION' => 7, 'ON DELETE' => 7,
        'ON UPDATE' => 7, 'UNION ALL' => 7,
        'CROSS JOIN' => 7, 'ESCAPED BY' => 7, 'FOR UPDATE' => 7, 'INNER JOIN' => 7,
        'LINEAR KEY' => 7, 'NO RELEASE' => 7, 'OR REPLACE' => 7, 'RIGHT JOIN' => 7,
        'ENCLOSED BY' => 7, 'LINEAR HASH' => 7, 'STARTING BY' => 7,
        'AND NO CHAIN' => 7, 'FOR EACH ROW' => 7, 'NATURAL JOIN' => 7,
        'PARTITION BY' => 7, 'SET PASSWORD' => 7, 'SQL SECURITY' => 7,
        'CHARACTER SET' => 7, 'IF NOT EXISTS' => 7, 'TERMINATED BY' => 7,
        'DATA DIRECTORY' => 7, 'UNION DISTINCT' => 7,
        'DEFAULT CHARSET' => 7, 'DEFAULT COLLATE' => 7, 'FULL OUTER JOIN' => 7,
        'INDEX DIRECTORY' => 7, 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' => 7, 'SUBPARTITION BY' => 7,
        'GENERATED ALWAYS' => 7, 'RIGHT OUTER JOIN' => 7,
        'NATURAL LEFT JOIN' => 7, 'START TRANSACTION' => 7,
        'LOCK IN SHARE MODE' => 7, 'NATURAL RIGHT JOIN' => 7, 'SELECT TRANSACTION' => 7,
        'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET' => 7,
        'NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN' => 7,
        'NATURAL RIGHT OUTER JOIN' => 7, 'WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT' => 7,

        'BIT' => 9, 'XML' => 9,
        'ENUM' => 9, 'JSON' => 9, 'TEXT' => 9,
        'ARRAY' => 9,
        'SERIAL' => 9,
        'BOOLEAN' => 9,
        'DATETIME' => 9, 'GEOMETRY' => 9, 'MULTISET' => 9,
        'MULTILINEPOINT' => 9,
        'MULTILINEPOLYGON' => 9,

        'INT' => 11, 'SET' => 11,
        'BLOB' => 11, 'REAL' => 11,
        'FLOAT' => 11,
        'BIGINT' => 11, 'DOUBLE' => 11,
        'DECIMAL' => 11, 'INTEGER' => 11, 'NUMERIC' => 11, 'TINYINT' => 11, 'VARCHAR' => 11,
        'LONGBLOB' => 11, 'LONGTEXT' => 11, 'SMALLINT' => 11, 'TINYBLOB' => 11,
        'TINYTEXT' => 11,
        'CHARACTER' => 11, 'MEDIUMINT' => 11, 'VARBINARY' => 11,
        'MEDIUMBLOB' => 11, 'MEDIUMTEXT' => 11,

        'BINARY VARYING' => 15,

        'KEY' => 19,
        'INDEX' => 19,
        'UNIQUE' => 19,
        'SPATIAL' => 19,
        'FULLTEXT' => 19,

        'INDEX KEY' => 23,
        'UNIQUE KEY' => 23,
        'FOREIGN KEY' => 23, 'PRIMARY KEY' => 23, 'SPATIAL KEY' => 23,
        'FULLTEXT KEY' => 23, 'UNIQUE INDEX' => 23,
        'SPATIAL INDEX' => 23,
        'FULLTEXT INDEX' => 23,

        'X' => 33, 'Y' => 33,
        'LN' => 33, 'PI' => 33,
        'ABS' => 33, 'AVG' => 33, 'BIN' => 33, 'COS' => 33, 'COT' => 33, 'DAY' => 33,
        'ELT' => 33, 'EXP' => 33, 'HEX' => 33, 'LOG' => 33, 'MAX' => 33, 'MD5' => 33,
        'MID' => 33, 'MIN' => 33, 'NOW' => 33, 'OCT' => 33, 'ORD' => 33, 'POW' => 33,
        'SHA' => 33, 'SIN' => 33, 'STD' => 33, 'SUM' => 33, 'TAN' => 33,
        'ACOS' => 33, 'AREA' => 33, 'ASIN' => 33, 'ATAN' => 33, 'CAST' => 33, 'CEIL' => 33,
        'CONV' => 33, 'HOUR' => 33, 'LOG2' => 33, 'LPAD' => 33, 'RAND' => 33, 'RPAD' => 33,
        'SHA1' => 33, 'SHA2' => 33, 'SIGN' => 33, 'SQRT' => 33, 'SRID' => 33, 'ST_X' => 33,
        'ST_Y' => 33, 'TRIM' => 33, 'USER' => 33, 'UUID' => 33, 'WEEK' => 33,
        'ASCII' => 33, 'ASWKB' => 33, 'ASWKT' => 33, 'ATAN2' => 33, 'COUNT' => 33,
        'CRC32' => 33, 'FIELD' => 33, 'FLOOR' => 33, 'INSTR' => 33, 'LCASE' => 33,
        'LEAST' => 33, 'LOG10' => 33, 'LOWER' => 33, 'LTRIM' => 33, 'MONTH' => 33,
        'POWER' => 33, 'QUOTE' => 33, 'ROUND' => 33, 'RTRIM' => 33, 'SLEEP' => 33,
        'SPACE' => 33, 'UCASE' => 33, 'UNHEX' => 33, 'UPPER' => 33,
        'ASTEXT' => 33, 'BIT_OR' => 33, 'BUFFER' => 33, 'CONCAT' => 33, 'DECODE' => 33,
        'ENCODE' => 33, 'EQUALS' => 33, 'FORMAT' => 33, 'IFNULL' => 33, 'ISNULL' => 33,
        'LENGTH' => 33, 'LOCATE' => 33, 'MINUTE' => 33, 'NULLIF' => 33, 'POINTN' => 33,
        'SECOND' => 33, 'STDDEV' => 33, 'STRCMP' => 33, 'SUBSTR' => 33, 'WITHIN' => 33,
        'ADDDATE' => 33, 'ADDTIME' => 33, 'AGAINST' => 33, 'BIT_AND' => 33, 'BIT_XOR' => 33,
        'CEILING' => 33, 'CHARSET' => 33, 'CROSSES' => 33, 'CURDATE' => 33, 'CURTIME' => 33,
        'DAYNAME' => 33, 'DEGREES' => 33, 'ENCRYPT' => 33, 'EXTRACT' => 33, 'GLENGTH' => 33,
        'ISEMPTY' => 33, 'IS_IPV4' => 33, 'IS_IPV6' => 33, 'QUARTER' => 33, 'RADIANS' => 33,
        'REVERSE' => 33, 'SOUNDEX' => 33, 'ST_AREA' => 33, 'ST_SRID' => 33, 'SUBDATE' => 33,
        'SUBTIME' => 33, 'SYSDATE' => 33, 'TOUCHES' => 33, 'TO_DAYS' => 33, 'VAR_POP' => 33,
        'VERSION' => 33, 'WEEKDAY' => 33,
        'ASBINARY' => 33, 'CENTROID' => 33, 'COALESCE' => 33, 'COMPRESS' => 33,
        'CONTAINS' => 33, 'DATEDIFF' => 33, 'DATE_ADD' => 33, 'DATE_SUB' => 33,
        'DISJOINT' => 33, 'DISTANCE' => 33, 'ENDPOINT' => 33, 'ENVELOPE' => 33,
        'GET_LOCK' => 33, 'GREATEST' => 33, 'ISCLOSED' => 33, 'ISSIMPLE' => 33,
        'JSON_SET' => 33, 'MAKEDATE' => 33, 'MAKETIME' => 33, 'MAKE_SET' => 33,
        'MBREQUAL' => 33, 'OVERLAPS' => 33, 'PASSWORD' => 33, 'POSITION' => 33,
        'ST_ASWKB' => 33, 'ST_ASWKT' => 33, 'ST_UNION' => 33, 'TIMEDIFF' => 33,
        'TRUNCATE' => 33, 'VARIANCE' => 33, 'VAR_SAMP' => 33, 'YEARWEEK' => 33,
        'ANY_VALUE' => 33, 'BENCHMARK' => 33, 'BIT_COUNT' => 33, 'COLLATION' => 33,
        'CONCAT_WS' => 33, 'DAYOFWEEK' => 33, 'DAYOFYEAR' => 33, 'DIMENSION' => 33,
        'FROM_DAYS' => 33, 'GEOMETRYN' => 33, 'INET_ATON' => 33, 'INET_NTOA' => 33,
        'JSON_KEYS' => 33, 'JSON_TYPE' => 33, 'LOAD_FILE' => 33, 'MBRCOVERS' => 33,
        'MBREQUALS' => 33, 'MBRWITHIN' => 33, 'MONTHNAME' => 33, 'NUMPOINTS' => 33,
        'ROW_COUNT' => 33, 'ST_ASTEXT' => 33, 'ST_BUFFER' => 33, 'ST_EQUALS' => 33,
        'ST_LENGTH' => 33, 'ST_POINTN' => 33, 'ST_WITHIN' => 33, 'SUBSTRING' => 33,
        'TO_BASE64' => 33, 'UPDATEXML' => 33,
        'BIT_LENGTH' => 33, 'CONVERT_TZ' => 33, 'CONVEXHULL' => 33, 'DAYOFMONTH' => 33,
        'EXPORT_SET' => 33, 'FOUND_ROWS' => 33, 'GET_FORMAT' => 33, 'INET6_ATON' => 33,
        'INET6_NTOA' => 33, 'INTERSECTS' => 33, 'JSON_ARRAY' => 33, 'JSON_DEPTH' => 33,
        'JSON_MERGE' => 33, 'JSON_QUOTE' => 33, 'JSON_VALID' => 33, 'MBRTOUCHES' => 33,
        'MULTIPOINT' => 33, 'NAME_CONST' => 33, 'PERIOD_ADD' => 33, 'STARTPOINT' => 33,
        'STDDEV_POP' => 33, 'ST_CROSSES' => 33, 'ST_GEOHASH' => 33, 'ST_ISEMPTY' => 33,
        'ST_ISVALID' => 33, 'ST_TOUCHES' => 33, 'TO_SECONDS' => 33, 'UNCOMPRESS' => 33,
        'UUID_SHORT' => 33, 'WEEKOFYEAR' => 33,
        'AES_DECRYPT' => 33, 'AES_ENCRYPT' => 33, 'CHAR_LENGTH' => 33, 'DATE_FORMAT' => 33,
        'DES_DECRYPT' => 33, 'DES_ENCRYPT' => 33, 'FIND_IN_SET' => 33, 'FROM_BASE64' => 33,
        'GEOMFROMWKB' => 33, 'GTID_SUBSET' => 33, 'JSON_INSERT' => 33, 'JSON_LENGTH' => 33,
        'JSON_OBJECT' => 33, 'JSON_PRETTY' => 33, 'JSON_REMOVE' => 33, 'JSON_SEARCH' => 33,
        'LINEFROMWKB' => 33, 'MBRCONTAINS' => 33, 'MBRDISJOINT' => 33, 'MBROVERLAPS' => 33,
        'MICROSECOND' => 33, 'PERIOD_DIFF' => 33, 'POLYFROMWKB' => 33, 'SEC_TO_TIME' => 33,
        'STDDEV_SAMP' => 33, 'STR_TO_DATE' => 33, 'ST_ASBINARY' => 33, 'ST_CENTROID' => 33,
        'ST_CONTAINS' => 33, 'ST_DISJOINT' => 33, 'ST_DISTANCE' => 33, 'ST_ENDPOINT' => 33,
        'ST_ENVELOPE' => 33, 'ST_ISCLOSED' => 33, 'ST_ISSIMPLE' => 33, 'ST_OVERLAPS' => 33,
        'ST_SIMPLIFY' => 33, 'ST_VALIDATE' => 33, 'SYSTEM_USER' => 33, 'TIME_FORMAT' => 33,
        'TIME_TO_SEC' => 33,
        'COERCIBILITY' => 33, 'EXTERIORRING' => 33, 'EXTRACTVALUE' => 33,
        'GEOMETRYTYPE' => 33, 'GEOMFROMTEXT' => 33, 'GROUP_CONCAT' => 33,
        'IS_FREE_LOCK' => 33, 'IS_USED_LOCK' => 33, 'JSON_EXTRACT' => 33,
        'JSON_REPLACE' => 33, 'JSON_UNQUOTE' => 33, 'LINEFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'MBRCOVEREDBY' => 33, 'MLINEFROMWKB' => 33, 'MPOLYFROMWKB' => 33,
        'MULTIPOLYGON' => 33, 'OCTET_LENGTH' => 33, 'OLD_PASSWORD' => 33,
        'POINTFROMWKB' => 33, 'POLYFROMTEXT' => 33, 'RANDOM_BYTES' => 33,
        'RELEASE_LOCK' => 33, 'SESSION_USER' => 33, 'ST_ASGEOJSON' => 33,
        'ST_DIMENSION' => 33, 'ST_GEOMETRYN' => 33, 'ST_NUMPOINTS' => 33,
        'TIMESTAMPADD' => 33,
        'CONNECTION_ID' => 33, 'FROM_UNIXTIME' => 33, 'GTID_SUBTRACT' => 33,
        'INTERIORRINGN' => 33, 'JSON_CONTAINS' => 33, 'MBRINTERSECTS' => 33,
        'MLINEFROMTEXT' => 33, 'MPOINTFROMWKB' => 33, 'MPOLYFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'NUMGEOMETRIES' => 33, 'POINTFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_CONVEXHULL' => 33,
        'ST_DIFFERENCE' => 33, 'ST_INTERSECTS' => 33, 'ST_STARTPOINT' => 33,
        'TIMESTAMPDIFF' => 33, 'WEIGHT_STRING' => 33,
        'IS_IPV4_COMPAT' => 33, 'IS_IPV4_MAPPED' => 33, 'LAST_INSERT_ID' => 33,
        'MPOINTFROMTEXT' => 33, 'POLYGONFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_GEOMFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_LINEFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_POLYFROMWKB' => 33, 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' => 33,
        'GEOMCOLLFROMWKB' => 33, 'MASTER_POS_WAIT' => 33, 'POLYGONFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'ST_EXTERIORRING' => 33, 'ST_GEOMETRYTYPE' => 33, 'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'ST_INTERSECTION' => 33, 'ST_LINEFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_MAKEENVELOPE' => 33,
        'ST_MLINEFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_MPOLYFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_POINTFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_POLYFROMTEXT' => 33, 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' => 33,
        'CHARACTER_LENGTH' => 33, 'GEOMCOLLFROMTEXT' => 33, 'GEOMETRYFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'JSON_MERGE_PATCH' => 33, 'NUMINTERIORRINGS' => 33, 'ST_INTERIORRINGN' => 33,
        'ST_MLINEFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_MPOINTFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_MPOLYFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'ST_NUMGEOMETRIES' => 33, 'ST_POINTFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_SYMDIFFERENCE' => 33,
        'JSON_ARRAY_APPEND' => 33, 'JSON_ARRAY_INSERT' => 33, 'JSON_STORAGE_FREE' => 33,
        'JSON_STORAGE_SIZE' => 33, 'LINESTRINGFROMWKB' => 33, 'MULTIPOINTFROMWKB' => 33,
        'RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS' => 33, 'ST_LATFROMGEOHASH' => 33, 'ST_MPOINTFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'ST_POLYGONFROMWKB' => 33,
        'JSON_CONTAINS_PATH' => 33, 'MULTIPOINTFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_BUFFER_STRATEGY' => 33,
        'ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE' => 33, 'ST_GEOMCOLLFROMTXT' => 33, 'ST_GEOMCOLLFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_GEOMFROMGEOJSON' => 33, 'ST_LONGFROMGEOHASH' => 33, 'ST_POLYGONFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE' => 33, 'MULTIPOLYGONFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_GEOMCOLLFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'ST_GEOMETRYFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_NUMINTERIORRINGS' => 33, 'ST_POINTFROMGEOHASH' => 33,
        'UNCOMPRESSED_LENGTH' => 33,
        'MULTIPOLYGONFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_LINESTRINGFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_MULTIPOINTFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_MULTIPOINTFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'MULTILINESTRINGFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_MULTIPOLYGONFROMWKB' => 33,
        'MULTILINESTRINGFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_MULTIPOLYGONFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMWKB' => 33, 'ST_MULTILINESTRINGFROMWKB' => 33,
        'GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMTEXT' => 33, 'ST_MULTILINESTRINGFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'VALIDATE_PASSWORD_STRENGTH' => 33, 'WAIT_FOR_EXECUTED_GTID_SET' => 33,
        'ST_GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMWKB' => 33,
        'ST_GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMTEXT' => 33,
        'WAIT_UNTIL_SQL_THREAD_AFTER_GTIDS' => 33,

        'IF' => 35, 'IN' => 35,
        'MOD' => 35,
        'LEFT' => 35,
        'MATCH' => 35, 'RIGHT' => 35,
        'INSERT' => 35, 'REPEAT' => 35, 'SCHEMA' => 35, 'VALUES' => 35,
        'CONVERT' => 35, 'DEFAULT' => 35, 'REPLACE' => 35,
        'DATABASE' => 35, 'UTC_DATE' => 35, 'UTC_TIME' => 35,
        'LOCALTIME' => 35,
        'CURRENT_DATE' => 35, 'CURRENT_TIME' => 35, 'CURRENT_USER' => 35,
        'UTC_TIMESTAMP' => 35,
        'LOCALTIMESTAMP' => 35,
        'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' => 35,

        'NOT IN' => 39,

        'DATE' => 41, 'TIME' => 41, 'YEAR' => 41,
        'POINT' => 41,
        'POLYGON' => 41,
        'TIMESTAMP' => 41,
        'LINESTRING' => 41,
        'MULTILINESTRING' => 41,
        'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION' => 41,

        'CHAR' => 43,
        'BINARY' => 43,
        'INTERVAL' => 43
    );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While a solution attempt is appreciated, please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58824731/edit) to include an explanation of the code you've included. The code is *very* long, and most wouldn't bother using it without some form of description.